# С и переменное число аргументов

Tags: c, printf

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос появился. Есть ли в C удобный способ последовательно затолкать элементы массива в функции с переменным количеством аргументов.

Поясню на примере:

```
void
print_arr(char *fmt, char **arr, int arrsz)
{
    printf(fmt, ???);
}
```

Или обязательно писать обвёртку, которая будет с массивами работать?

Можно ли как-то стандартыми средствами преобразовать *arr* в тип **va_list** и передать vprintf?

Заранее спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988290/populating-a-va-list

Comment: Хороший вопрос (особенно если на него кто-то найдет положительный ответ).

IMHO стандартными методами никак. 

Например, ддя gcc в x86-64 нужно первые 6 параметров поместить в регистры, а остальные в стек.

Comment: Тот факт, что похожее можно сделать на Objective-C: [
fake va_list in ARC](
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211996/fake-va-list-in-arc/8217755#8217755) заставляет думать, что это можно сделать, но к сожалению я не знаю чистый С, чтобы опустить этот код на более низкий уровень.

Comment: @Stanislaw, мне кажется (возможно ошибаюсь, т.к. на Objective-C не пишу), что это не тот случай (также, как и случай, рассмотренный в ответе).

И у Вас и в ответе @khaos, вызываемая функция **принимает  va\_list, как аргумент** и все усилия вызывающей стороны сводятся к моделированию этой структуры (т.е. прототип вызываемой функции вида *f(va\_list);*).

А у ТС прототип типа *f(...);* соответственно машинный код **доступа к параметрам** будет другой.

В этом существенное отличие.

Comment: А что мешает организовать **легальный** `va_list` через `va_start( ..., arr[-1] )`?

Comment: @mega, не пойдёт, arr не помещён в аргументы почленно, там только адрес первого элемента-указателя

Comment: @Sercxjo, не понял! Для `va_list` нужен просто "плоский" набор аргументов, вектор в этом плане как раз годится, не вижу проблем.  
 --  
А, все, понял! @Sercxjo, обратите внимание на сигнатуру еще раз: `char **arr`. Массив указателей как раз доступен "почленно".

Comment: @mega, не будет работать (по крайней мере в x_86-64).

Даже если плюнуть на warning и для удовлетворения компилятора сделать функцию с переменным числом аргументов (без этого просто не компилируется).

gcc-шный bultin va_start упорно кладет в va_list вовсе не содержимое массива.

Comment: Элементы не лежат в стеке, а макрос va_start может на это расчитывать.
Вообще-то вопрос был в другом, требуется не итерировать массив, а преобразовать его в вид принимаемый библиотечной функцией, а набор макросов в stdarg.h даёт возможность только проитерировать аргументы в порядке, как они лежат в стеке, но не заполнить стек перед вызовом функции по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Согласен, способ только для `x86`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно появились компиляторы C, в которых va_list реализовано по-другому, но c давних пор это работало:

```
char *args[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
vprintf("%s, %s, %s\n", args);
```

gcc выдаёт предупреждение, которое легко снимается преобразованием:

```
vprintf("%s, %s, %s\n", (va_list)args);
```

результат тот который нужен:

```
$ gcc valist.c 
$ ./a.out
one, two, three
```

Для gcc под amd64 найдено экспериментально следующее извращение:

```
char *args[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
struct { int x; char **y, **z; } valist = {48, &args, &args};
vprintf("%s, %s, %s\n", (void*)&valist);
```

Если sizeof(va_list) == 4 то первый способ скорее всего работает, во втором случае sizeof(va_list) == 24

Comment: @sercxjo, в 32-bit x-86 gcc Ваш способ действительно работает, а вот в x-86 64-bit при приведении типа компилятор выдает

    va4.c:47:27: error: cast specifies array type

а без преобразования, компилируется с warning, но рушится по segmentation fault.

--

Собственно, я уже писал  здесь в комментариях про передачу части аргументов в регистрах для 64-bit x-86.

Comment: Я подтверждаю то, что сказал avp:

На Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2 ... RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

    vprintf_example.c:8: error: cast specifies array type

А без преобразования:

vsprintf_example.c:8: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘vprintf’ from incompatible pointer type

Так что, выходит, нельзя считать, что этот ответ (который только что был ещё и принят) является по-настоящему верным, хотя наверняка задача gg4me и решена.

Comment: @avp Поэкспериментировал с gcc -S -m64 , да Вы правы, что-то там намудрёно, регистры кладутся в стек, а в переменной типа va_list длиной 24 байта два указателя и ещё каких-то 2 счётчика. Указатели на область сохранённых регистров (48 байт) и остальных аргументов. Теоретически можно заполнить эту структуру так, чтобы всё указывало на один массив указателей, но это будет специально для данной архитектуры.

Comment: @sercxjo, а вот с таким

      long aa[] = {201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,-1};
      struct { int x; void *y, *z; } valist;
      valist.x = 48; valist.y = (void *)aa; valist.y = (void *)aa;

**Вы здорово придумали (+1)!!!**

--

Работает с массивом данных размером с регистр (т.е. с адресами будет все OK). Проверял на i5-2500 (думаю на любой 64-bit x-86 тоже будет работать).

Comment: в общем нужен только один указатель, но y Или z я не разобрался

Comment: @serxcjo, я проверил при z = 0 все работает (наоборот нет).

Comment: при таком заполнении тоже работает: {0, &aa[6], &aa}
первый счётчик показывает смещение прибавляемое ко второму указателю, пока оно не достигнет 48 байт, тогда берутся данные по первому указателю. Счётчик вроде 4х-байтный, назначение старшей части x мне осталось неясным.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE.** Если нельзя менять сигнатуру функции, стандартных способов сделать такое нет. **Однако**, по крайней мере в *Visual C++*, есть возможно скастовать массив ноль-терминированных строк в `va_list`.

```
vprintf(fmt, reinterpret_cast<va_list>(arr));
```

---

Попробуйте посмотреть [вот это](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html).
Приведённая там реализация через `va_list` скрыта внутри функции и внешне выглядит очень даже хорошо.

По-другому, напрямую, думается, можно реализовать такое ассемблерной вставкой, работая напрямую с регистрами. Но это неудобно и чревато.

Comment: @khaos Проблема в том что в моём случае функции передаётся массив аргументов и мне нужно скормить его аналогу printf. Причём сам интерфейс функции я менять не могу.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Может, это вам подойдёт.