# Как работают функции с переменным числом аргументов в C?

Tags: c, функции, переменные

Навеяно вопросом [Как работает execlp, что за последний аргумент NULL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537962/)? Полистал ответы на схожие вопросы, но подробного описания не нашёл:

1. [Функции с переменным числом параметров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419928/)
2. [Как в C объявить функцию с переменным числом аргументов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408/)
3. [С и переменное число аргументов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/211999/)

И т.д.

P.S Предполагается, что читатель этого текста уже выпустился из детсада, и не задаёт вопросов уровня "Мне тут какую-то ошибку выдали, чо это?". И не путает C с C++.

Пинки, подзатыльники и прочие указания на "ты неправ" приветствуются.

Comment: Минусатор, был бы интересен ваш комментарий.

Comment: @VladD , ничё не понял :) "делитесь знаниями..." это тогда о чём?

Comment: Нет, мне интересно, чтобы тот, кто поставил минус (это не я), объяснил, что не так по его мнению.

Comment: @VladD, а, в этом смысле. Да фигня всё. Оно больше для себя пишется, больше для "упаковки", "сжатия" и "освежения" данных в собственной голове. А публичное выкладывание - это так, тест на адекватность изложения :) Плюсы или минусы пофиг.

Answer (score 5):

В языке C есть возможность объявлять и использовать функции с переменным числом аргументов. Возможность эта обеспечивается особенностями работы со стеком при вызове функций, но сейчас они подробно рассматриваться не будут, только практическая сторона вопроса. Магия, происходящая в `<stdarg.h>` тоже за рамками, любопытный да найдёт объяснение этому шаманству.

Прототип такой функции может выглядеть так, например:

```
void print_messages( const char * title, ... );
```

А вызов - так:

```
print_messages( "Вот что имею сообщить", 
                "это раз", "это два", "это три", NULL );
```

И печатать, соответственно:

```
Вот что имею сообщить:
 - это раз.
 - это два.
 - это три.
```

Ну и её реализация:

```
void print_messages( const char * title, ... ) {

    va_list ap;
    const char * message;
    va_start( ap, title );

    printf( "%s:\n", title );

    message = va_arg( ap, const char * );
    while( message ) {
        printf( " - %s.\n", message );
        message = va_arg( ap, const char *);
    }

    va_end( ap );
}
```

Самой важной проблемой тут является определение конца списка аргументов. В данном случае использовался `NULL` для его отметки. Но это не всегда приемлемо. Например, когда `NULL` является допустимым значением аргумента. Или, скажем, `0`/`-1` в случае целых чисел.

Первое решение этой проблемы - передать количество аргументов первым параметром:

```
void print_numbers( size_t amount, ... ) {

    va_list ap;
    int number;
    va_start( ap, amount );

    printf( "Total numbers: %zu, let's go! ", amount );
    while( amount-- ) {
        number = va_arg( ap, int );
        printf( " [%d]", number );
    }

    va_end( ap );
}
```

Вызов:

```
print_numbers( 3, 11, 22, 33 );
```

Этот метод может применяться только тогда, когда в функцию передаются аргументы одного типа. Того же можно добиться, передавая массив значений с его размером. Но это не всегда оправдано. Да и рассматривается сейчас технологическая демка, а не целесообразность (которая *всегда* на совести программиста, но на то к нему `/dev/brain` и прилагается).

Шёпотом: ну и TMTOWTDI в сях тоже бывает, хи-хи...

А что делать, если аргументы могут быть разных типов? Тут на помощь приходит метод под названием "формат". Любой сишник с ним знаком по `*printf*`. Но это не интересно. Придумаем своё, на том же принципе.

Определимся:

- символ 'c' означает char
- 's' - short
- 'l' - long
- 'z' - char *

Прототип:

```
void print_something( const char * format, ... );
```

Реализация:

```
 void print_something(const char * fmt, ...) {

  va_list ap;
  va_start( ap, fmt );
  /* Гусары, молчать! */
  long l;
  int i;
  char c;
  char *z;


  while( *fmt ) {

    switch( *fmt ) {
        case 'c':
            /* см дальше */
            c = (char)va_arg( ap, char );
            printf( "char: '%c'\n", c );
            break;

        case 's':
            /* см дальше */
            s = (short)va_arg( ap, short );
            printf( "short: '%d'\n", s );
            break;

        case 'i':
            i = va_arg( ap, int );
            printf( "int: '%d'\n", i );
            break;

        case 'l':
            l = va_arg( ap, long );
            printf( "long: '%lu'\n", l );;
            break;

        case 'z':
            z = va_arg( ap, char * );
            printf( "char *: '%s'\n", z );;
            break;

        default:
            printf( "Хрен знает что передали: '%c'\n", *fmt );
            break;
    }
    fmt++;
  }
}
```

Дальше: `char`, `short` и прочее, которое меньше `int`.

Эти строчки возбуждают компилятор:

```
c = (char)va_arg( ap, char );
/* 'char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' */
s = (short)va_arg( ap, short );
/* 'short' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' */
```

Выводы делать не буду, оставлю на домашнее задание.