# Функция с переменным числом параметров в C, без макросов

Tags: c, функции

Не могу найти ошибку в коде, функция `sum`, с переменным числом параметров, первым аргументом принимает число аргументов, далее сами аргументы. В цикле ссылаюсь не на те адреса. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sum(int k, ...)
{
    int *p = &k;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i){
       ++p;
       sum += *p;
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
}

int main()
{
   sum(3, 1, 2, 3);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: без макросов va_* Вы не сможете сделать это переносимо.

Comment: Вы работаете не в соответствии со стандартом - какой помощи вы хотите? Описать вам, как работать через `va_list` - так вы сами от этого отказываетесь... Простите, но примерно получается "я тут вытащил из стены электропровода и прикрутил к ним телевизор, но он не работает. Помогите! Включать телевизор в розетку не предлагать..."

Comment: @Harry скорее уж "хочу посмотреть телевизор. Как мне это сделать? Смотреть телевизор не предлагать".

Comment: Это вопрос в билете к сессии

Comment: Это вопрос в билете к сессии,если знаете как это сделать,помогите,пожалуйста. @Harry

Comment: @ИгорьКорпенко законно - никак. Остальное зависит от компилятора и, возможно, от ключей с которыми собирается приложение.

Comment: приведенный выше код работает под линуксом /gcc но только если собрано в 32битном режиме. Почему? просто так сложились звезды

Comment: Простите уж, не львовская политехника? Там какой-то препод учит современному С++ по своей книге, где в качестве **СТАНДАРТА ЯЗЫКА** (!) рассматривается реализация Borland C++ 3.1 со всеми его, скажем так, особенностями...

Comment: @KoVadim В Си принято соглашение о вызовах `cdecl`, т.е. все параметры передаются через стек. Так что если знать число и размеры переданных типов, их вполне можно аккуратно снять со стека. У меня приведенный код также работает в MinGW-w64 под windows.

Comment: логично, что работает - это же почти тот же gcc.

Comment: под 64 битной архитектурой не будет работать, потому как там параметры передаются через регистры (первые штук 6), и только потом через стек. Такое соглашение. И тут манипулирование стеком. clang идет дальше и занимается этим даже под 32битную платформу...

Comment: Где Вы учились,если не секрет? @KoVadim

Comment: в школе, в институте. Но это не относится к вопросу.

Comment: @KoVadim, "clang идет дальше" -- даже упомянутый BC 3.1 в своей 16-битности не брезговал регистрами, если явно не сказано `cdecl` :)

Comment: Это решается через ABI на платформу, тем не менее флаги компиляции могут сильно влиять на результат. Скорее всего ваш преподаватель считает *va_list* и компанию не макросами.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int sum(size_t k, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, k);

    int sum = 0;

    while (k--) {
        int num = va_arg(ap, int);
        sum += num;
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
   printf("%i\n", sum(3, 1, 2, 3));
}
```

Без `stdarg.h` работать будет не везде. Про макросы `va_*` можно почитать в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538296/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) вопросе. Ваш код может работать на некоторых платформах, а может и не работать. Все зависит от того, как в функцию передаются аргументы (см. [соглашения о вызове](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5)).