# Проблема с переменным количеством параметров в функции c++

Tags: c++, linux

Пример из учебника В.В. Подбельского "Язык C++" 2004 года выпуска. 
Понятно, что книга старая и всё в ней старое, вопрос в другом.
Пример компилируется нормально без каких-либо ошибок или предпреждений.
Но при работе выдаёт что попало.

```
//p6-04.cpp - меняются тип и количество параметров функции
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long minimum (char z, int k, ...); // прототип функции
  cout << "\n\tminimum('l', 3, 10L, 20L, 30L) = " <<
               minimum('l', 3, 10L, 20L, 30L);
  cout << "\n\tminimum('i', 4,  11,   3,   10,  4) = " <<
                    minimum('i', 4,  11,   3,   10,  4);
  cout << "\n\tminimum('k', 2,   0,  64) =  " << minimum('k', 2, 0, 64) << endl;
  return 0;
}

// функция с переменным списком параметров
long minimum(char z, int k, ...)
{
    if (z == 'i')
        { int *pi = &k + 1; // настроились на первый необязательный параметр
        int  min = *pi;   // значение первого необязательного параметра
        for (; k; k--, pi++)
        min = min > *pi ? *pi : min;
        return (long)min;
      }

   if (z == 'l')
      { long *pl = (long*)(&k + 1);
        long min = *pl; // значение первого параметра
        for (; k; k--, pl++)
        min = min > *pl ? *pl : min;
        return (long)min;
      }
   cout << "\nОшибка! Неверно задан 1-й параметр:";
   return 2222L;
}
```

При запуске выдаёт ерунду, обращаясь видимо не к тем адресам, к которым нужно.

```
    zozo@pew:~/exe$ ./p6-04

    minimum('l', 3, 10L, 20L, 30L) = -2360847195084685312
    minimum('i', 4,  11,   3,   10,  4) = -549677576
Ошибка! Неверно задан 1-й параметр:
    minimum('k', 2,   0,  64) =  2222
```

Должен возвращать следующее:

```
zozo@pew:~/exe$ ./p6-04

    minimum('l', 3, 10L, 20L, 30L) = 10
    minimum('i', 4,  11,   3,   10,  4) = 3
Ошибка! Неверно задан 1-й параметр:
    minimum('k', 2,   0,  64) =  2222
```

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает корректно.
Компилятор g++, ОС Linux.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774980/Функция-с-переменным-числом-параметров-в-c-без-макросов

Answer (score 3):

В с++ не следует использовать функции с переменным числом параметров. Для этого есть `initializer_list` и `tuple`. В с++ не следует использовать нетипобезопасные конструкции с волшебными флажками для индикации типов и с-style кастованием. Для этого есть шаблоны. Соответственно ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cassert>

template<typename x_Value> auto
minimum(::std::initializer_list<x_Value> items)
{
    assert(0 < items.size());
    auto p_item{items.begin()};
    auto p_min{p_item};
    for(;;)
    {
        ++p_item;
        if(items.end() == p_item)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(*p_item < *p_min)
        {
            p_min = p_item;
        }
    }
    return *p_min;
}

int main()
{
  ::std::cout << "\n\tminimum(3L, 10L, 20L, 30L) = " <<
    minimum({3L, 10L, 20L, 30L});
  ::std::cout << "\n\tminimum(4, 11, 3, 10, 2, 4) = " <<
    minimum({4,  11, 3, 10, 2, 4});
  return 0;
}
```

[онлайн компилятор](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oURax0FiWDEhmg1x)

Comment: но все же интересно:  пространство имен   std  может быть и неглобальным, что вы постоянно отмечаете это четыремя точками?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `std` может даже не быть пространством имен... [Развернутый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762601/Надо-ли-писать-два-двоеточия-перед-std/762754#762754).

Comment: если стремиться застраховаться от всех  возможных  и невозможных случаев, то можно и  с каждым кодом приложить море обработок исключений и  комментарий.   Вы же не берете с собой оружие для защиты от кракодилов, когда идете в бассейн?.. Ведь никто не давал гарантию, что туда кто то случайно или  специально не спрятал кракодила?..  Кстати  по вашей ссыльке и мой ответ есть

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `namespace Crash { namespace std { template<typename> struct vector { vector(...) { ::std::terminate(); } }; }}`

Answer (score 3):

Это грязный системно-зависимый хак... В реальном коде так делать не следует ровным счётом **никогда**... Но если уж очень хочется его запустить и поиграться, то его необходимо собрать под архитектуру x86 (в 32-х битном режиме), для этого надо скормить gcc ключик `-m32` (подразумевая конечно, что у тебя обычная ныне amd64-система, а не какой-нибудь arm):

```
 $ g++ -m32 crap.cpp -o crap
 $ ./crap

        minimum('l', 3, 10L, 20L, 30L) = 10
        minimum('i', 4,  11,   3,   10,  4) = 3
Ошибка! Неверно задан 1-й параметр:
        minimum('k', 2,   0,  64) =  2222
```

Как сделать правильно описано, например, здесь: [Как работают функции с переменным числом аргументов в C?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538296/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Учебник не стыкуется с реальностью g++ передаёт всё через регистры

```
    movl    $4, %r9d    #,
    movl    $10, %r8d   #,
    movl    $3, %ecx    #,
    movl    $11, %edx   #,
    movl    $4, %esi    #,
    movl    $105, %edi  #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    _Z7minimumciz   #
```

Я пользуюсь

```
#include <stdarg.h>
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap,k);
  va_arg(ap,int);
  va_end(ap);
```

и не жалуюсь.