# Переменное число параметров в функции

Tags: c++, алгоритм, функции

Данный код работает некорректно. Он должен выводить то количество параметров, что указано ему аргументом `num`, используя указатель на адрес аргумента `first`, но что-то идёт не так...
Я знаю о том, что существует библиотека `stdarg.h`. Но интересует меня именно этот вариант.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void func(int num, int first, ...)
{
    int *ptr = &first;
    while (num--)
    {
        cout << *ptr++ << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    func(3, 1, 2, 3);
    // Output: 1, 1, rand

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с переменным количеством параметров в функции c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814892/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что так и только  так - с использованием `va_list`!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
using namespace std;

void func(int num, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,num);
    while(num--)
    {
        cout << va_arg(ap,int) << endl;
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    func(3, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

Все остальные методы - как минимум *непереносимы*!

Понимаете, вы примерно хотите так: я знаю, что такое аппендицит, знаю о хирургических методах лечения, но почему после прыганья с бубном у меня дело доходит до перитонита? Как правильно прыгать с бубном?

**НИКАК**

Например, ваш код срабатывает с 32-разрядном VC++ 2017, и не работает в VC++ 64-разрядном. Вы хотите для каждого отдельного компилятора, каждого его режима писать свой код?...

Comment: Хотелось бы попросить минусующего пояснить, в чем у меня ошибка - чтобы я больше ее не допускал.