# Функции с переменным количеством аргументов. Аргументы строки

Tags: c++, c

Не выводится вторая строка, в случае ее использования, как я понял, я не правильно увеличиваю аддрес. Как надо?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void show_operands(char*, ...);
//void to_add_code(char*);

int main(void)
{
    char bin_num1[17] = "", bin_num2[17] = "";

    printf("->Ввод операндов ...\nВведите два числа(в прямом коде) через пробел:\n$ ");
    scanf("%s%s", bin_num1, bin_num2);
    show_operands(bin_num1, bin_num2, "0");

    /*printf("->Перевод в дополнительный код ...\n");
    to_add_code(bin_num1);
    to_add_code(bin_num2);
    show_operands(bin_num1, bin_num2, '0');*/

    return 0;     
    }

void show_operands(char* first, ...)
{
     char** ptr = &first;
     printf("Операнд1: %s\n", *ptr);
     ptr++;
     if (*ptr != "0")
         printf("Операнд2: %s\n", *ptr);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что вторая строка расположена прямо за первой?...

Comment: не считая того, что это UB по-большому счёту.

Comment: и да, вы берёте адрес не на саму строку. а на указатель (!!). А в функцию кстати аргументы с конца часто приходят. https://ideone.com/6Eqy4B

Comment: Думаю Вам нужен stdarg.h

Comment: И еще (*ptr != "0"). Нельзя так сравнивать строки...

Comment: Очередная львовская политехника... Ну какое чмо учит студентов так работать с функциями с переменным числом аргументов? "И я б их к стенке ставил через одного и направлял на них груженый самосвал" (с) Высоцкий. Посмотрите, например,[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817677/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/817681#817681), как нужно правильно работать с этими `...`...

Comment: Прочитайте про vararg